# Setting a checkbox to unchecked when clicking on drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'd like to be able to uncheck a checkbox if my drop down has been selected using jQuery.  I feel like I might almost be there but can't figure out why it isn't working. For example, I click MR but then I change to doctor - MR stays selected.

```
<script>
$('.multiple-choice').click(function(){
$('input').prop('checked', false);
});
</script>

<fieldset  class="title-box">

<span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Mr" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titlemr" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlemr" id="mr-label">Mr</label></span>
<span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Mrs" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titlemrs" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlemrs" id="mrs-label">Mrs</label></span>
<span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Miss" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titlemiss" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlemiss" id="miss-label">Miss</label></span>
<span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Ms" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titlems" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlems" id="ms-label">Ms</label></span>

    <span><label for="dropdown">Other</label>
    <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" class="multiple-choice"> 


<option value="Dr" name="othertitle1" id="othertitle1">Dr</option>
<option value="Rev">Rev</option>
<option value="Sir">Sir</option>
<option value="Sist">Sist</option></select>
</fieldset>
```

```js
<script>
 $('.multiple-choice').click(function(){
    $('input').prop('checked', false);
    });
    </script>
```

```html
    <fieldset  class="title-box">
       
 <span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Mr" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titlemr" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlemr" id="mr-label">Mr</label></span>
 <span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Mrs" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titlemrs" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlemrs" id="mrs-label">Mrs</label></span>
 <span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Miss" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titlemiss" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlemiss" id="miss-label">Miss</label></span>
 <span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Ms" onclick="titlehandler(this)" id="titlems" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlems" id="ms-label">Ms</label></span>

  <span><label for="dropdown">Other</label>
  <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" class="multiple-choice"> 
                           

    <option value="Dr" name="othertitle1" id="othertitle1">Dr</option>
    <option value="Rev">Rev</option>
    <option value="Sir">Sir</option>
    <option value="Sist">Sist</option></select>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Place your JS code _after_ the HTML markup. Currently it's executed before the HTML lines are loaded.

Comment: Or wrap it inside a `$(document).ready`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<script>
$('.multiple-choice').click(function(){
    $("input[type='radio'").each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, and if I wanted to clear the drop down when I clicked back into the title would I also use this code but reversed?

Answer (score 1):

Either put this part at the bottom of your file or wrap it in a `$(document).ready()` callback.

```
<script>
$('.multiple-choice').click(function(){
$('input').prop('checked', false);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! If I wanted to clear the drop down when I clicked back into the title would I also use this code but reversed?

Answer (score 1):

I removed `onclick="titlehandler(this)"` and it seems to be working fine:

```js
$('.multiple-choice').click(function() {
  $('input').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="title-box">

  <span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Mr" id="titlemr" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlemr" id="mr-label">Mr</label></span>
  <span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Mrs"  id="titlemrs" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlemrs" id="mrs-label">Mrs</label></span>
  <span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Miss"  id="titlemiss" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlemiss" id="miss-label">Miss</label></span>
  <span><input type="radio" name="title" value="Ms"  id="titlems" th:field="*{title}" /> <label for="titlems" id="ms-label">Ms</label></span>

  <span><label for="dropdown">Other</label>
    <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" class="multiple-choice"> 


<option value="Dr" name="othertitle1" id="othertitle1">Dr</option>
<option value="Rev">Rev</option>
<option value="Sir">Sir</option>
<option value="Sist">Sist</option></select>
</fieldset>
```